# mysql joins, doesn't seem to work (Select_full_join)

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I'm having some problems with joining my tables.

When doing the query, I get a red flag:

> Select_full_join
>
> The number of joins that do not use indexes. If this value is not 0, you should carefully check the indexes of your tables.

... I also get a lot of slow_queries

Is there anything else I need to do to make it work, except setting up an index?
I saw that you can add relationships between tables, or foreign keys, maybe that is what I need?

I'm a noob when it comes to mysql.

Here's my query:

```
SELECT 
    m.numberOfPlayers as totalNumberOfPlayers,
    COUNT(p.userId) AS currentNumberOfPlayers 
FROM 
    matches_active m 
        LEFT JOIN matches_players p ON p.matchId = m.id 
WHERE 
    m.id = 5922;
```

...and here's my tables:

`matches_active`

```
id   int(11)
numberOfPlayers int(11)

PRIMARY  id
```

`matches_players`

```
userId   int(11)
matchId  int(11)   

PRIMARY    userId 
           matchId
```

Comment: You should define an index on the column on which the join is based. Also, make sure they are of the same type. A definition of a foreign key is not necessary, but may make things easier.

Comment: If you are newbie in mysql just try to make inner join via phpmyadmin..it's quiet easy Tell me for more clarification ..

Comment: Please show your table structure including any keys.

Comment: An index may or may not fix your problems.  The key is showing your query.  Without the query, anyone trying to help is just shooting in the dark.

Comment: Thanks for replies. I edit the question above

Answer (score 1):

When your queries are using aggregates functions, you should to `GROUP BY` all fieldS that not has been aggregated

```
SELECT 
    m.numberOfPlayers as totalNumberOfPlayers,
    COUNT(p.userId) AS currentNumberOfPlayers 
FROM 
    matches_active m 
        LEFT JOIN matches_players p ON p.matchId = m.id 
GROUP BY
    m.numberOfPlayers
WHERE 
    m.id = 5922;
```